# how to convert json to a dataframe using json_normalize?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, normalize

I'm trying to covert an api response from json to a dataframe in pandas. the problem I am having is that de data is nested in the json format and I am not getting the right columns in my dataframe.

The data is collect from a api with the following format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10T11:40:13.437Z",
            "score": 87,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": 20.010000228881836
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": 34.4900016784668
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 418
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 166
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "comp": "lux",
                    "value": 961.4000244140625
                },
                {
                    "comp": "spl_a",
                    "value": 45.70000076293945
                }
            ],
            "indices": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": -2
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10T11:40:03.413Z",
            "score": 87,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": 20.040000915527344
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": 34.630001068115234
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 418
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 169
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 5
                },
                {
                    "comp": "lux",
                    "value": 960.2000122070312
                },
                {
                    "comp": "spl_a",
                    "value": 46
                }
            ],
            "indices": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        },
```

### edit as you can see it are more sets of data

What I already tried is the following: I have converted the JSON format into a dict and then I normalized it with the normalize function. see the code as following:

```
data = r.json() 

works_data = json_normalize(data=data['data'], record_path=['sensors'],meta=['timestamp'])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(works_data)
print(df)
```

the result I am getting is:

```
 comp        value                 timestamp
0      temp    21.059999  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
1     humid    31.250000  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
2       co2   407.000000  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
3       voc   136.000000  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
4      pm25     3.000000  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
5       lux  1302.099976  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
6     spl_a    46.299999  2019-04-10T12:39:05.062Z
```

the result I need is as following:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WId4v.png)

is there somebody who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your works_data:

```
data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10T11:40:13.437Z",
            "score": 87,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": 20.010000228881836
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": 34.4900016784668
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 418
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 166
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "comp": "lux",
                    "value": 961.4000244140625
                },
                {
                    "comp": "spl_a",
                    "value": 45.70000076293945
                }
            ],
            "indices": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": -2
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10T11:40:03.413Z",
            "score": 87,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": 20.040000915527344
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": 34.630001068115234
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 418
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 169
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 5
                },
                {
                    "comp": "lux",
                    "value": 960.2000122070312
                },
                {
                    "comp": "spl_a",
                    "value": 46
                }
            ],
            "indices": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        }]}


from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd        

df = pd.DataFrame()
for each in data['data']:
    timestamp = each['timestamp']
    temp_df = json_normalize(data=each, record_path=['sensors']).T

    columns = list(temp_df.iloc[0])
    data_values = list(temp_df.iloc[1,:])

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data_values + [timestamp]], columns=columns + ['timestamp'])

    df = df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)



print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
        temp      humid    co2  ...         lux      spl_a                 timestamp
0  20.010000  34.490002  418.0  ...  961.400024  45.700001  2019-04-10T11:40:13.437Z
1  20.040001  34.630001  418.0  ...  960.200012  46.000000  2019-04-10T11:40:03.413Z

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need the only thing is that I have more than 1 of those sets of json so what the code now does is that it makes from all the sets columns so I have a lot of columns. but what I want is that it only makes 1 set of columns and then just adds more rows see the edited json data for a better sample

Comment: so new row for each timestamp?

Comment: mate you are awesome! this is exactly what I needed